# Separate Power Supply on Sensors?

Tags: sensor, voltage-regulator

I have this homework that I need to justify power fluctuations on electronic devices. I had this idea (though don't know if it is right) that such fluctuations/spikes affect the operation/stability of an IC/sensor.

Am I thinking right that if i have a single power source coming from a +3.3v voltage regulator (amperage output is close enough on the total needs of what are connected to it) and this supplies some 4 pcs of sensors, 6 different IC drivers (differential, encoders, dmx, etc), 1 ESP8266 module.

- 3v3 300mA voltage regulator
- 50mA - 4 sensors consumes
- 50mA - 6 different ic drivers consumes
- 220mA - wifi module consumes

I have the following questions:

1. Do the 4 sensors or some of it would not work properly (output value not accurate) if all of this run at the same time/one at a time at microspeed by a microcontroller?
2. Would it be better to isolate the voltage supplies of sensors like putting them on a different voltage regulator?
3. Would the voltage regulator just for the sensors be switching
   regulator or normal linear regulators?
4. I read that switching regulators are efficient but produces high noises, does that affect the output of the sensors and how?

Comment: These are **ten** complex questions in one. Start smaller, please. Focus on one question, remove the others.

Comment: @MarcusMüller ^^; Thanks a lot for the edit. Uhm, regarding your suggestion on focus on one question, then that means, should I create different questions for each of my questions even though these are related (these questions are right?)

Comment: well, I said "focus". You can't anyone expect to answer all your questions in one answer – that'd be to write a rather long book.  It's often very helpful for oneself to find the question that oneself finds most fundamental, and get an answer to that – the rest might very well fall into place by itself after one understands the basics!

Answer (score 2):

If you do not daisy chain your ICs, then it should work well enough.
Yes you need decoupling caps. With them any fluctuations that might occur will not affect your power supply and thus rest of your circuit.

As far as choosing a linear or a switching regulator, give it a read:

https://www.digikey.in/en/articles/techzone/2017/sep/understanding-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-linear-regulators